# Using Python for basic Quadratic Inequalities

Tags: python, math, quadratic, inequality

I'm struggling to figure out how to properly use Python to solve a quadratic inequality.

I'm trying to learn Python a bit and I'm trying to work through a quadratic inequality. I have a range of numbers for x from -5 to 5 and I want to use the equation y(x) = x**2 to calculate y(x) for all values greater than 0.

```
x = (-5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

def y(x):
    if x >= 0:
        return x**2

print(y(x))
```

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'tuple' and 'int'

Comment: Your y(x) function is going to return None for negative values of x. I doubt that's what you want. You should filter out the negative values *before* calling y(x).

Answer (score 1):

Define your function for all numbers (remove the `if` from the function), loop over the numbers in the tuple `x` and put your `if` in the loop (this avoids the `None`s that the function will return by default when called by negative numbers, and avoids the not so good solution of double checking both in the function and in the loop):

```
def y(x):
    return x**2

for n in x:
    if n >= 0:
        print(y(n))
```

Comment: Thank! This makes a lot of sense. The problem I was trying to solve was somewhat similar to this but much more complicated (for the purposes of learning I simplified it to be able to ask my question).

Answer (score 0):

x is a tuple in your code so you are trying to apply the `**` operator to the whole tuple.

Try this.

```
for number in x:
    print(y(number))
```